# ......Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, php, android, jquery

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined...........

```
import Login from '../components/Login.jsx';
import { useDeps, composeWithTracker, composeAll } from 'mantra-core';
export const composer = ({context, clearErrors}, onData) => {
  const { LocalState } = context();
  const error = LocalState.get('LOGIN_ERROR');
  onData(null, { error });
  // clearErrors when unmounting the component
  return clearErrors;
};
export const depsMapper = (context, actions) => ({
  loginUser: actions.users.login,
  clearErrors: actions.users.clearErrors,
  context: () => context
});
export default composeAll(composeWithTracker(composer), useDeps(depsMapper))(Login);
```

Comment: C#, PHP, Android and JS...? Did you just pick random tags for this question? Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: whatever `actions` is has no property called `users` (this line `actions.users.login` ) - the rest only you and your god knows

Answer (score 1):

Because `actions.users` is undefined.

I think `actions` doesn't have a property named `users`.

Please check your **actions**.